# getElementByTagName not working?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I am applying a different background color to all even rows by dynamically assigning the class "even" to them using javascript. I am calling the alternamte() function onload of the body tag.

At first, I was using getElementById to get the table object and my code worked fine. However, I am suppose to apply this styling to ALL tables on my page, so I need to use get element by tag name.

Once I made the chane to getElementByTagName, my code stopped working and I have been trying to find out the root of the problem for a while now with no success.  I was wondering if someone can help me understand why my code stopped working after I made the change to getElementByTagName?

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function alternate(){
        var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");   
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");   

        for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){           
            //change style of even rows 
            //(odd integer values, since we're counting from zero)
            if(i % 2 == 0){ 
                rows[i].className = "even"; 
            }     
        }   
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please keep your developer's console open. It would have pointed out the error

Comment: I'd suggest you use adjust your code to use `rows[i].className += " even";` to account for any rows that might already have classes. Your method overrides them.

Comment: [I grew extra arms.](http://theminorityreport.co/stixblog/files/2012/07/demotivational-posters-quadruple-facepalm.jpg)

Comment: ...and FYI, you don't need the second `getElementsByTagName("tr")`, you can just use the `.rows` collection of the table,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName), plural.  It returns a HTMLCollection

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
```

(if you're confident that there's a `<table>` on the page.)

If you want to do things to *all* the `<table>` elements, you'd have to do something like this:

```
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");   

    for (var ti = 0; ti < tables.length; ++ti) {
      var rows = tables[ti].getElementsByTagName("tr");   
      for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){           
        //change style of even rows 
        //(odd integer values, since we're counting from zero)
        if(i % 2 == 0){ 
            rows[i].className = "even"; 
        }     
      }   
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this worked for me:) However, since we are adding '[0]' to your code, wouldn't that mean that this style is just applied to the first table on the page? what if I wanted to apply this style too ALL tables on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getElementsByTagName` instead of `getElementByTagName` (getElementsByTagName return multiple node elements )

```
 var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0], trs, rl;  
 vat tl= table.length;
 while(tl--){
        trs = tables[tl].getElementsByTagName("tr");
        rl = trs.length;
        while(rl--){
           if(rl % 2 == 0){ 
              trs[rl].className = "even"; 
           } 
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed it to getElementsByTagName and its still not working :(

Comment: Sorry, I was busy. I know you already got your answer, this another way.

Answer (score -2):

getElementsByTagName() returns an array matching the selector. Hence try

```
var table = getElementsByTagName('table')[indexnumber];
```

Comment: There's also no `getElementsByTagName()` function. It should be a method of an Element, or the document,.